# User controlled sorting of multiple ranges in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that builds a few tables (of x columns each, but having a variable number of rows per table). All of these tables are in the same sheet.

I would like each such table to be sortable by columns independently of other tables (when the user clicks the header of each column of that table). How can I make this work through app scripts (since these scripts build the tables)?

I tried using filters, but I can't create one per table since only one can exist per sheet.

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of sorts do you want?

Comment: @Cooper, ascending/descending etc.

Comment: I meant alphabetic, or numerical or special types like dates..  If you want to sort by another method other than alphabetic then you have to create a special compare function for the sorting loop.

Comment: @Cooper, it will be either alphabetic or numeric but generally the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The following modeless dialog is used to collect informaton pertaining to the sort

[image]

code:

```
function sortSelectedRange(obj) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange(obj.range);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  if (obj.sortType == 'alphabetical') {
    rg.sort({ column: parseInt(obj.column), ascending: true })
  }
  if (obj.sortType == 'numerical') {
    const sortidx = parseInt(obj.column) - rg.getColumn();
    vs.sort((a, b) => {
      let vA = a[sortidx];
      let vB = b[sortidx];
      if (obj.sortDir == 'ascending') {
        return vA - vB;
      } else {
        return vB - vA;
      }
    });
    rg.setValues(vs);
  }
}

function selectRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  return rg.getA1Notation();
}

function selectColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  return rg.getColumn();
}
```

launches the sort dialog:

```
function launchMySortDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'), 'Sort Dialog');
}
```

html(filename:'ah2.html'):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style> 
      input {margin: 1px 2px 1px 0;} 
      #radio1,#radio2{border:1px solid black;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
     <input type="text" name="range" placeholder="Select Range" id="range" readonly /><input type="button" value="Select Range" onClick="selectRange();" />
     <br /><input type="text" name="column" placeholder="Select Column" id="column" readonly /><input type="button" value="Select Column" onClick="selectColumn();" />
     <div id='radio2'>Sort Type
     <br /><input type="radio" name="sortType" checked value="alphabetical"/> alphabetical
     <br /><input type="radio" name="sortType" value="numerical" /> numerical
     </div>
     <div id='radio1'>Sort Direction
     <br /><input type="radio" name="sortDir" checked value="ascending"/> ascending
     <br /><input type="radio" name="sortDir" value="descending" /> descending
     </div>
     <br /><input type="button" value="Sort" onClick="sortSelectedRange(this.parentNode);" />
     
    </form> 
     <script>
      function sortSelectedRange(obj) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
        .sortSelectedRange(obj)
      }
      function selectRange() {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(v){document.getElementById('range').value=v})
        .selectRange();
      }
      function selectColumn() {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(v) {document.getElementById('column').value=v})
        .selectColumn();
      }
     </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

I colored the background to make it easier to create the demo video.

Comment: This took me about an hour but it was interesting I haven't done something like this for a while.

Comment: This looks great. Thank you for the time and effort you put in.

But, I was wondering how different this would be from the "sort range" option under the data menu. Your solution, like this one, needs the range and sorting column to be specified.

Can this be made more user-friendly, like how sorting of columns work with filters which only requires the column header to be clicked for the associated table to get sorted?

Comment: This method allows you to click any where in the column which seems just as easy to me.  But if you wish to change it to column header feel free to do so.  It's quite a bit different from the sort function of the data menu since it does not do a numerical sort at all.